# Rich Text Area LWC Default Value in Screen Flow

Tags: lightning-web-components

Anyone know if it is possible to set a default value property (or work around) for a custom Rich Text Area Component in a screen flow like you can other components? I have a flow to gather information from users and some of it I need to offer the ability to format the text so that it can be assembled into a finished document later. The user needs to be able to run the flow then come back and edit or add information as it is available. For all other components I can grab what was saved previously to the DB and set as default values. But that property doesn't seem to exist for the lightning-input-rich-text component.